# Open File Dialog with exclude Filter (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I'm currently writing a small script for Excel to import csv files. Therefore I integrated an open file dialog with a csv-filter.

```
 With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Datei wählen"
    .InitialFileName = "c:\test\*.csv"
    .Show

    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
       'do something 
    End If
 End With
```

So far this works fine for me. But unfortunately I have different types of csv-files like

- file.csv
- test.csv
- file_1.csv
- lala_2.csv
- ...

Can i modify my filter in that way, that he only shows me the files without '_#' in front of '.csv'?

Thanks for your help.
Best wishes

Stefan

Comment: AFAIK, `FileDialog.Filters` only supports the `*` wildcard. If this is a requirement, designing your own file dialog may be the only option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you are very limited here and can only use the wildcards `*` and `?` which do not allow to exclude characters.

You can have a filter like this:

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Datei wählen"
    .InitialFileName = "c:\test\test_*.csv"
    .Show

    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
       'do something 
    End If
End With
```

To retrieve all CSV files starting with `test_`but that's the best you can do.

See **[doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa432281(v=office.12).aspx)** on Microsoft's website.

Comment: Pretty sure for the `.Filters` that it's only `*` - using a `?` gives a run-time error "Invalid procedure call or argument".

Comment: @Comintern these are for the `InitialFileName` property, I have successfully tested with `.InitialFileName = "c:\test\test_?.csv"` and a file named `test_1.csv`. I haven't tried with the `Filters` which don't seem to be necessary here

Comment: Right, but the OP was asking about a filter.

Comment: @Comintern `InitialFileName` does filter. OP asked how to *modify* his filter, which is already using this property.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply.

In principle the approach by GôTô works fine, The only thing is, what to do if the '_#' is larger than nine? 

'?' allows only one character. In best case I need an unknown amount of numbers. E.g. test_1223345.csv Is this somehow possible?

Comment: @Stefan actually your question was to show only the files without the `_#` while your comment suggests the contrary? You could use `test_*.csv` but would get any file with this prefix, even `test_aaaa.csv`

Comment: @GôTô your right it was more a general question. Your suggestion by using '*' instead of '?' works. Thanks a lot. 
Nevertheless, it would be great to have the possibility to use regular expression here :-) Anyway thank again for your help.